# How do I link my Google Profile to my blog?

Tags: google-search

Google search results show a link to the Google Profile for the author of appropriate search results, how do I ask Google to do this for the content I've created?

I have a necessary parts (blog + Google Profile).

[image: Google Search results showing author Google Profile]

Comment: Nice! Can we get this for our Stack Overflow profiles, please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Add `<a rel="me" href="https://profiles.google.com/your_ID">Author Name</a>` to your **About me** page. If you don't have one, create it.
2. Add `<a rel="author" href="http://yourwebsite.com/about/">Author Name</a>` to each post/page you create.
3. Sign in to your Google Profiles account and under links, add a new custom link that points to your "About Me" page. Tick the option that says "This page is specifically about me" and save the changes.

[Here](http://www.labnol.org/internet/author-profile-in-google/19775/) are some tips.

Jeff Atwood does it by adding `<a rel="author" href="https://profiles.google.com/codinghorror1">Jeff Atwood</a>` to its pages.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, I'd viewed the source on Jeff's site, but missed the `rel` links

Comment: so sorry but I am very new to blogging. where you have /your_ID ... i assume thats my google id. is that my display name? or my email? im trying to link my google account to my wordpress blog.

Comment: @candice Login to Gmail and then go to https://profiles.google.com/ You will be redirected to `https://profiles.google.com/YOUR_ID/` (or to `https://plus.google.com/YOUR_ID/posts`). That's your ID.